# I'm looking for good book recommendations on investments

Tags: investing, reference-material

I'm looking for a list of reliable books/University level textbooks on Investing. All kinds of books from introductory to expert, so that I can become an expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Goldman Sachs](http://www.goldmansachs.com/) actually published a recommended reading list with titles written by its former employees which cover a variety of investing topics and could serve as a useful starting point to check out the titles.

[Here](http://www.stat.unc.edu/faculty/cji/890-11/Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf) is the link. Definitely a good place to get started.